# Maximum function nesting level of '512' reached, aborting

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I have 2 model: ***User*** and ***Team***.
    - A user belongs to a team.
    - A team has many users.

And here is my `User` model.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable {

    use Notifiable, HasRole;

    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $with = ['team', 'role'];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function team()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
    }
}
```

`Team` model:

```
class Team extends Model {

    protected $with = ['leader'];

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('membersCount', function ($builder) {
            $builder->withCount('members');
        });
    }

    public function leader()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'leader_id');
    }

    public function members()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

When I tried to eager load  `team` in User model by using `protected $with = ['team'];`, it ends up with a error

`Maximum function nesting level of '512' reached, aborting!`

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you've created a recursive dependency between team and users, though can't say for sure not knowing how eloquent works internally.

Comment: try to change `leader()` method calling `hasOne` against `belongsTo`

Comment: @JonStirling yes, you're right. My app need to be like that. A user belongs a team and a team have to have a leader (user_id). I don't know how can I handle it.



@ArtemIlchenko it doesn't work, because my `users` table never has `leader_id` field

Answer (score -2):

Putting the below in my `php.ini` worked for me.
Basically you need to increase the nesting level.

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1024
```

Comment: With an infinite loop, this'll just add an extra few milliseconds before the same error occurs.